# internaly linking to home page (/index) using ajax when htacess redirects home page to mydomain.com

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am using a redirect in my Apache .htaccess file to send all traffic from index.html to mydomain.com.  To do this, I am using the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I'm having trouble with now is using a relative path to my home page when calling content in to a `<div>` using AJAX.

If I want to get content from /index.html, I get a 404 error.  I can over come this by using an absolute path ie. "http://mydomain.com", but is there a way I can still use the relative path to the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, I'd say your URL parameters/anchor isn't going through the rewrite. You can fix that with the QueryStringAppend `QSA` flag like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```